# Why $\det_{\mathcal B_n}(e_1,...,e_p,d_{p+1},d_{p+2}+c_{p+2},...,c_n+d_n)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The aim of the exercise is to prove that $$\det\begin{pmatrix}B&D\\0&C\end{pmatrix}=\det(B)\det(C)$$
where $B\in \mathbb R^{p\times p}$, $C\in \mathbb R^{q\times q}$, $n=p+q$ and $M:=\begin{pmatrix}B&D\\0&C\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

Let $\mathcal B_n(e_1,...,e_n)$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$, $E=Span\{e_1,...,e_p\}$ and $E'=Span\{e_{p+1},...,e_n\}$. Therefore $\mathbb R^n=E\oplus E'$.

Set $M=(m_{j})_{1\leq j\leq n}$ where $m_{j}$ are the column of $M$ and are defined as $m_j=b_j+0$ if $1\leq j\leq p$ and $m_j=d_j+c_j$ if $p+1\leq j\leq n$. Therefore

$$\det(M)=\det_{\mathcal B_n}(m_1,...,m_n)=\det_{\mathcal B_n}(b_1,...,b_p,c_{p+1}+d_{p+1},...,c_n+d_n).$$

Let $$\alpha :E^p\to \mathbb R$$
defined as $$\alpha (x_1,...,x_p)=\det_{\mathcal B_n}(x_1,...,x_p,c_{p+1}+d_{p+1},...,c_n+d_n).$$
Recall that $\{e_1,...,e_p\}$ is a basis of $E$. Therefore, by linearity :
$$\alpha (e_1,...,e_p)=\det_{\mathcal B_n}(e_1,...,e_p,c_{p+1},...,c_n+d_n)+\underbrace{\det_{\mathcal B_n}(e_1,...,e_p,d_{p+1},...,c_n+d_n)}_{=0},$$
but I don't understand why the last term is $0$.

Comment: d_{p+1} is a linear combination of e_i

Comment: @MikeHawk: Thank you but how do you know that ?

Comment: Petulant downvoting is not a great strategy. Certainly does not encourage one to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

Note that if $C$ is invertible we have
$\begin{bmatrix} B & D \\ 0 &  C\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I & DC^{-1} \\ 0 &  I\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 &  C\end{bmatrix}$ and so we see that
$\det \begin{bmatrix} B & D \\ 0 &  C\end{bmatrix} = = \det B \det C$.

Since this is true for all invertible $C$, $\det$ is continuous and the invertible matrices are dense we see that it is true for all $C$.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. By the why, your hint is equivalent to prove that $\det \begin{pmatrix}B&D\\0&C\end{pmatrix}=\det(B)\det(C)$, so I don't really see in what it helps.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Peter: The computation of $\det$ for the first matrix is straightforward since there is exactly one permutation that needs to be examined. The computation for the second is also straightforward for similar reasons.

Comment: I did downvoted (please don't take it against you). I'm not criticizing your mathematical skills that are very huge. The reason for my downvote it's that proving your hint is almost equivalent to prove what I asked (even if it's more straightforward, it's almost the same)

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Hawk mentioned $d_{p+1}$ is a linear combination of $(e_i)_{1\le i\le p}$ since it is an element of $\mathbb R^p$ which has as base $(e_i)_{1\le i\le p}$

Comment: First, you just copy a comment (that is not very well see). Then, how do you know that $d_{p+1}$ is a linear combinaison of $(e_i)_{1\leq i\leq p}$ ?

Comment: Yes I know, I did that since I am new and I cannot comment, so it was my only solution. As I told you $(e_i)_{i\le p}$ is a base of $\mathbb R^p$. And $d_{p+1}$ is in $\mathbb R^p$

Comment: +1: This is a perfectly good answer, I do not understand the downvote.

Comment: @copper.hat: In fact I did downvote, but I forgot that less 50 reputation can't comment. I tried to cancel my downvote, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, I forgot the fact that you can't comment. And thank you for your answer.